# How to force HTTP access instead of HTTPS?

Tags: linux, networking, protocols

I want to accomplish something unique and use HTTP instead of HTTPS
for using all kinds of different websites, and was wondering
if anyone has any ideas about how to accomplish this feat.
The internet is very difficult to search these days, and gives results
like...search with https! And basically ignores my requests.

I think it's interesting, and am always looking for unique ways
to use technology which afford us different benefits. I think http
is interesting because I have seen a lot of different websites making
strange unsolicited connections, and generally being up to lots of sneaky
behavior, so with http we can hopefully examine these types of connections
in more detail, and better understand sneaky behavior that evolves over time.

Anywho I am going to continue researching this line of thinking, and if anyone
out there in the void has an idea to input that may be helpful that would...
be helpful.

thank you

edit: so I'm digging around and found some basic answers
that are unhelpful to me, such as using firefox settings
to disable https redirection.

browser.fixup.fallback-to-https false

(doesn't alter the situation)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532471/firefox-redirects-to-https

I think that either our dns servers, or perhaps web servers
themselves will attempt to force us all to use https, so
perhaps the only true solution is going to be to deny the https protocol itself entirely on the local host, and if remote web servers refuse to connect via http than we can safely disregard them as insecure, and find alternatives.

It's also likely that in order for this strategy to succeed
we will need unique solutions instead, of just one solution, because technology will adapt new methods to inappropriately impose constraints on our, in this case, interactions with remote web servers.

So I'm pressing ahead with this issue and trying different things,
here's how I disabled https on the local host using gufw
(added a simple rule to deny incoming/outgoing https)
[img] https://i.imgur.com/LLdRltq.png [/img]

It's concerning because I've noticed that unsolicited connections
will come to, and from, my browser, and there's no way to know
what initiated these exchanges, or what they are doing.

Disabling https completely with my firewall on my own computer
prevents firefox from accessing lots of websites.. like this one:
unix.stackexchange.com and google. (they attempt to load in an infinite loop) However using a different web browser, lynx, I can connect to google with http immediately.

[img] https://i.imgur.com/qsjpxET.png [/img]

Comment: So apparently I am between 8-20 years too late to develop an understanding about https and it's inherent lack of security. And based on corporate agreements http is in the process of being phased out altogether, in secret, under the pretense of securing users privacy.https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/04/30/deprecating-non-secure-http/

Comment: I wonder what the actual use case is here.

Comment: If you connect to my website using http you'll get an immediate redirect to https. No other content is served over http. You'll find (you should find) many if not most websites do this as a matter of course

Comment: Disabling the port _named_ https is not at all the same thing as disabling https protocol; programs and even webpages can easily use any other port. However _most_ don't, so this does block you from nearly all of the web. It is true most modern websites access hundreds of resources from all over the place, many of them privacy and/or security risks, but they already did this in http long before massive hacking of http connections, plus the Snowden revelations of government surveillance, pushed nearly universal use of https. And none of this is related to Unix.

Comment: I'm sad to see the question accumulating downvotes.  It's a pertinent and clear question, even if the apparent goal of trying to force other services to continue to support HTTP for anything other than an HTTPS redirect isn't terribly-well thought out.

Comment: This is actually an interesting question, albeit unworkable. Too much software infrastructure (browsers, HSTS, 301 redirects to HTTPS, HTTP/2 requiring SSL, others) depends on HTTPS being available. Best advice I can give if you really need to snoop on HTTPS connections is try using [sslstrip](https://github.com/L1ghtn1ng/sslstrip).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot force a remote site to serve you through HTTP if it is configured only to serve though HTTPS.  It is common to configure the HTTP endpoint to simply redirect to the HTTPS endpoint as a convenience.

If a remote host is not listening for HTTP requests, you cannot force it to serve an HTTP response.  You can try to eschew HTTPS through client configuration but as you have found many sites and services only serve redirects to enciphered channels on the plaintext one.

Answer (score 2):

On the Internet, almost all sites that have anything interesting are https. The http-universe is shrinking fast. That means that the number of web sites that you can use for your http project is diminishing. Some sites may still have a redirect to the https site over http, but the era of the plain http sites is coming to an end.

Whatever your something unique is, start using https, or fall in obsolesce with the use of http.

Your DNS server will not force you to use https. That is a complete misunderstanding on how DNS works and how the network operates.